# Content linked to domain is not working but with subdomain it is working on nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have created several subdomain so that i can serve the subdomain related specific content. But the problem i am facing is that when i am trying to access the content related directly to my domain am not getting anything in return in nginx. Below is my configuration file

```
http {
       include       mime.types;
       default_type  application/octet-stream;

      server {
         listen       80;
         server_name  example.com www.example.com;
         root   /usr/share/nginx/myfile/dev/web;
         index index.html index.htm;

         location / {

         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

         }

       }

      server {
         listen       80;
         server_name  dev.example.com;
         root   /usr/share/nginx/myfile/dev/mobile;
         index index.html index.htm;

         location / {

         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

         }

       }

       server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  qa-crm.example.com;
       root   /usr/share/nginx/myfile/qa-crm;
       index  index.html index.htm;

       location / {

          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
          }

        }


       server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  qa.example.com;
       root   /usr/share/nginx/myfile/qa;
       index  index.html index.htm;

       location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

          }
       }
     }
```

**All server block are serving perfectly except the first one which contains the main domain name i.e. (example.com www.example.com)**

> **No idea what i am doing wrong here. I am new to nginx world**

Comment: what do happens when you try access the main domain? Can you post the logs?

Comment: - - [21/Apr/2020:07:47:52 +0000] "GET /  HTTP/1.1" 200 2245 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36" ... I get success but it loads blank page no error

Comment: Your config seems me right, but the root path of you main site seems wrong, are you sure that it is pointing to the right directory? However, I recommend you to configure a better log format, using the two directives below:

Comment: log_format  main  '$time_local  | $http_x_forwarded_for | $remote_addr | $scheme | $proxy_host | $host | "$request" |status_code:$status Bytes-Tx:$body_bytes_sent  Bytes-Rx:$request_length | "$http_referer" |"$http_user_agent"|cache_status:"$upstream_cache_status" |[UPSTREAM ADDR: "$upstream_addr"]|[TIME: request_time=$request_time|upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time|upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time|upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time]|[http_encoding=$http_accept_encoding]';

Comment: access_log /va/log/nginx/access.log main;

Comment: Sorry for late reply..
23/Apr/2020:06:45:10 +0000 | - | 49.33.134.58 | http | - | example.com | "GET / HTTP/1.1" |status_code:200 Bytes-Tx:2245 Bytes-Rx:409 | "-" |"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"|cache_status:"-" |[UPSTREAM ADDR: "-"]|[TIME: request_time=0.000|upstream_header_time=-|upstream_connect_time=-|upstream_response_time=-]|[http_encoding=gzip, deflate] ... @ BrunoPaiuca